# Android app giving Textview Error on Pie but running fine on Oreo

Tags: android, textview

My app works fine on Oreo but giving a Null pointer Exception on a particular Textview on Android Pie,To find the issue I tried commenting out the problem textview but it starts giving the same error on the immediate next text view although there are textviews above these as well which dont throw any error. I just cant figure out what the problem is, and if there is it should be crashing on every device. Maybe I need to change somethings in the manifest or app.gradle file in order to run it on a higher api level? Any help would be appreciated as I have my FYP next week :(

```
 @SuppressLint({"WrongViewCast", "SetTextI18n"})
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void Showpopup(View v) {


    final Spinner activity;
    RadioButton radiomal, radiofemal;
    EditText feet, inch, weiht, age;
    final TextView textview,save, fulname, result1, result2, result3, result4, com, carbs, protien, fat, water;


    mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.resultpopup);
    textview = mydialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
    activity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    save = mydialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
    fulname = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    radiomal = findViewById(R.id.radiomal);
    radiofemal = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiofemal);
    feet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feet);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    inch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inches);
    com = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    weiht = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    gen = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.gen);
    result1 = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.bmi);
    result2 =  mydialog.findViewById(R.id.bmr);
    result3 = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.healthy);
    result4 = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.calorie);
    carbs = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.carbs);
    protien = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.protien);
    fat = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.fat);
    water = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.water);

    DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    String f = feet.getText().toString();
    String i = inch.getText().toString();
    String w = weiht.getText().toString();
    String a = age.getText().toString();


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(f)) {
        Toast.makeText(caloriecalc2.this, " Enter full Height", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(i)) {
        Toast.makeText(caloriecalc2.this, " Enter full Height", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(w)) {
        Toast.makeText(caloriecalc2.this, " Please Enter Weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(a)) {
        Toast.makeText(caloriecalc2.this, " Please enter Age", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (radiomal.isChecked() || radiofemal.isChecked()) {//No Radio Button Is Checked


        int ft = Integer.parseInt(f);
        int in = Integer.parseInt(i);
        int ag = Integer.parseInt(a);

        float h = (float) (((ft * 12) + in) * 2.54);
        if (f != null && !"".equals(f) && i != null && !"".equals(i) && w != null && !"".equals(w)) {
            float wf = Float.parseFloat(w);
            float bmi = (wf / (h * h)) * 10000;
            result1.setText(precision.format(bmi));


            if (bmi < 18.5) {
                com.setText("You are Underweight");
            } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
                com.setText("You have a Healthy Weight");
            } else if (bmi >= 25) {
                com.setText("You are Overweight");
            }

        }
        if (f != null && !"".equals(f) && i != null && !"".equals(i)) {
            if (radiomal.isChecked()) {
                float hea = (float) (56.2 + (in * 1.41));
                result3.setText(precision.format(hea));
            } else if (radiofemal.isChecked()) {
                float hea = (float) (53.1 + (in * 1.36));
                result3.setText(precision.format(hea));
            }

        }
        if (a != null && !"".equals(a) && i != null && !"".equals(i) && f != null && !"".equals(f) && w != null && !"".equals(w)) {
            float wf = Float.parseFloat(w);
            float bmi = (wf / (h * h)) * 10000;
            if (radiomal.isChecked()) {

                float cal = (float) ((float) 88.36 + (13.39 * wf) + (4.799 * h) - (5.677 * ag));
                result4.setText(precision.format(cal));

                if (arr == 0) {
                    cal = (float) ((float) 88.36 + (13.39 * wf) + (4.799 * h) - (5.677 * ag));
                    result2.setText(precision.format(cal));


                    if (bmi < 18.5) {
                        float car = (float) (cal * 0.45);
                        carbs.setText((precision.format(car)));
                        float pro = (float) (cal * 0.35);
                        protien.setText(precision.format(pro));
                        float fa = (float) (cal * 0.20);
                        fat.setText(precision.format(fa));
                    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
                        float car = (float) (cal * 0.50);
                        carbs.setText((precision.format(car)));
                        float pro = (float) (cal * 0.25);
                        protien.setText(precision.format(pro));
                        float fa = (float) (cal * 0.25);
                        fat.setText(precision.format(fa));

                    } else if (bmi >= 25) {
                        float car = (float) (cal * 0.35);
                        carbs.setText((precision.format(car)));
                        float pro = (float) (cal * 0.40);
                        protien.setText(precision.format(pro));
                        float fa = (float) (cal * 0.25);
                        fat.setText(precision.format(fa));

                    }

                } else if (arr == 1) {
                    cal = (float) (((float) 88.36 + (13.39 * wf) + (4.799 * h) - (5.677 * ag)) * 1.2);
                    result2.setText(precision.format(cal));
```

result2.setText(precision.format(cal)); This is the particular line

Resultpopup layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
android:padding="5dp"
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#F4C599"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:textColor="#F47507"
    android:text="X"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/circlebackground"
   />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:textColor="#F47507"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_24"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#FA7C11"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#F45A67"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BMI"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bmi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Null"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    />


 </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#6CA0F8"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BMR"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bmr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Null"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#0AC1EF"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Water (ltr)"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/water"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Null"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />


    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#29AE05"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Healthy Weight"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/healthy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Null"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FA8B35"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calorie Intake"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calorie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Null"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Macro's Breakdown"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#F87302"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"/>


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#474745"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Protien"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/protien"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Null"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#052AAE"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carbohydrate"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carbs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Null"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ED0858"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fat"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Null"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="You are Healthy Weight"
    android:textColor="#FA7C11"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is the Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.login, PID: 7007
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.login.caloriecalc2.Showpopup(caloriecalc2.java:235)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please post the entire code of the `onClick()` method, or at least show us how `result2` gets set.

Comment: The error message says `result2` is null

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin I have compared it side by side on Oreo and Pie with the same input it runs fine on one crashes on the other.

Comment: You have not casted dialog2 as a TextView, try change mydialog.findViewById(R.id.bmr) to (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.bmr). Can you post your resultpopup layout?

Comment: @DavidWasser The whole method is like 700 lines so I included the important part, is it maybe because the method in this activity calls a layout which I have formatted as a custom dialog box , although it sets the text in above text boxes before result 2 without any error.

Comment: @LucaPizzini Although those are redundant casts but I tried it and it didn't work